# Decoding error on what appears to be valid JSON

Tags: php, json, decoding, lumen

I've got a problem regarding JSON.

The set-up is very simple. I'm using the Lumen framework and within the 'Controller' class I've got a function which gets some information from the database which I want to use in another controller called 'GameController'. Here's the code that matters:

```
class GameController extends Controller
{
...
public function index(Request $request) 
{       
       $jsonGame = $this->getItem('games', 'gametitle', $request->input('title')); 
}
...
}



class Controller extends BaseController
{
public function getItem($table, $column, $item)
{
    try{
        $result = app('db')->table($table)
                    ->where($column, $item)
                    ->take(1)
                    ->get();

        if(count($result) != 0) {
            return Response::json($result);
        }

        return Response::notFound('Item not found');
    } 
    catch(QueryException $e) {
       ...
    }
}
}
```

Now the problem is that, as I try to decode the json in the variable $jsonGame and check if there are no errors, there's always the errorcode 4 and the decoding failed. I've checked it with the following:

```
    if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) { 
         echo 'json';
     } else { 
         echo json_last_error(); // gives error code 4
     }
```

So then I began checking the json manually, and this is what it outputs.
The output of **echo $jsonGame**:

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type:  application/json Date:          Mon, 24 Jul 2017 12:58:03 GMT
>
> [{"gameid":2,"gametitle":"rocket
>   league","gamedescription":"","created_at":"2017-07-24
>   07:02:43","updated_at":"2017-07-24 07:02:43"}]

The output of **return $jsonGame**:

> [
>       {
>           "gameid": 2,
>           "gametitle": "rocket league",
>           "gamedescription": "",
>           "created_at": "2017-07-24 07:02:43",
>           "updated_at": "2017-07-24 07:02:43"
>       } 
>   ]

So as you can see the above seems to be valid JSON, and I'm melting my brain over this. Why isn't decoding working? Why does it give errorcode 4?

Comment: Please check this `$gameArray =json_decode($jsonGame , TRUE);`
what its return in $gameArray?

Comment: one more thing set this `header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');`

Comment: I have no idea of php  but your json response is a list that contains one object. Are you expecting this on your decoding? Because if you are expecting only the object (game), this might be the cause of your problem

Comment: If the above comments don't work, you might try checking your server logs for any errors or warnings.

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya, thank you for your response. The $gameArray as suggested returns completely nothing, totally empty. But after I set the 'header' the header information in the echo I got before is gone. But, still, the decoding seems to fail.

Comment: @Carlos it also happens on a 'normal' json string such as: 
{
    "title": "Resource not found",
    "detail": "Item not found",
    "code": 404
}

Still fails decoding.

Comment: @rideron89 I've looked through them, there's nothing :(